# How to update Battery Level in BLE Device with CoreBluetooth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        for c in service.characteristics!{
            print("---Characteristic found with UUID: \(c.uuid) \n")

            let uuid = CBUUID(string: "2A19")//Battery Level

            if c.uuid == uuid{
                //peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: c)//Battery Level
                peripheral.readValue(for: c)
            }
        }
    }
}
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
/* Battery Level */
    if (characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "2A19")) && (characteristic.value != nil){
        let value = characteristic.value
        let valueUint8 = [UInt8](value!)
        print("\(valueUint8)")
        print("\(valueUint8[0])")
        let batteryLevel: Int32 = Int32(bitPattern: UInt32(valueUint8[0]))
        print("\(batteryLevel)")

    }
}
```

I can read Battery Level value, but how to update Battery Level when the value changed?

Why `peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: c)` can't update?

Comment: The code looks ok on first glance. How do you know it _isn't_ working?

Comment: how exactly is it "isn't working"? Citing the doc: "When you enable notifications for the characteristic’s value, the peripheral calls the 
`peripheral(_:didUpdateNotificationStateFor:error:)`
 method of its delegate object to indicate whether or not the action succeeded. ", so you may want to implement the didUpdateNotificationStateFor:error part to check if you can set notification for the battery.

Comment: if i got BatteryLevel value,
how to update BatteryLevel Value every 5 seconds from BLE Device?

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion on this? I am having similar issues. I've used the exact same methodology on a custom service characteristic and it works great. Same methodology on the battery level and it doesn't seem to work. Instead it just shows my iOS device's battery level. I suspect this may be one of those "tacitly immutable" characteristics unfortunately...