# What is the iOS equivalent of NSLevelIndicator?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, nslevelindicator

I'd like to show a battery indicator of a Bluetooth peripheral in my iOS app.

**Is there a version of [NSLevelIndicator (macOS)](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/indicators/level-indicators/) but that I could use in iOS?**

The closest alternative I found is reversing the [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview) but it's based on animation and I don't think it's a great idea for an animation to last for hours (slow of course).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750632/how-to-update-battery-level-in-ble-device-with-corebluetooth-in-swift

Comment: @Scriptable I think the question is more about the built-in UI element rather than getting the actual value

Comment: ah yeah it is, thanks David, i somehow missed that

Comment: I believe the keyword you need is 'gauge'. See for instance here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gauge

Comment: Ah, thank you @koen, wasn't aware of that. Found a great tutorial here then https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/150/how-to-create-a-custom-gauge-control-using-uikit